# How can I make a keyboard shortcut to turn off zoom?

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys, compiz

In compiz the "fit zoomed area to window" is pretty neat. It will zoom in so that a given windows covers the full screen.

What I'm missing here is a way to zoom out back to the default level.

I.e. if I'm zoomed in N%, how can I simply get back to 0% zoom?

I have a key to zoom out; but I need to press it a whole bunch of times which is not what I want.

I've also figured out that if I set "zoom level" to it's maximum (3.0),
then my zoom out key does bring it back to 0%. But now the zoom in key goes too close and is unusable. I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this (one where I don't have to disable other functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! You will need CompizConfig installed:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it up and search for `zoom` in the top left search bar.

[image]

Switch to the "specific zoom" tab and click "disabled", under "Zoom Specific Level 1":

[image]

Check the "enabled" checkbox and then click "Grab key combination" to set your desired shortcut.  Click "OK".

[image]

Make sure that "Specific zoom factor" is set to `1.00`.

You're done!